Getting data- values from links on page to JS
I currently have a table on my page generated by PHP from a MySqli DB, which contain a name and x and y coordinates. however this means displaying the x,y and ID data on the page. I use JS to rerad the x and y in the onclick listener, I need to modify my code so that I do not need to show this info to the user. my current code is below.
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".systemname").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $row = $(this).parent().parent();
    var x = $row.children().eq(2).text() + "px";
    var y = $row.children().eq(3).text() + "px";
    var m = $row.children().eq(4).text() + ".jpg";
    var i = $row.children().eq(5).text();
    $('#mapinfo').html(m);  
    var imageUrl = m;
    $("#mapcontent").css("background-image", "url(<?=$imglnk?>)");
    $("#pointer").css({"left": x, "top": y});
    $("#systeminfo").load('getsysteminfo.php?id='+i);
    
  });
});
</script>

I now need to modify my code to be able to use the following (or if there is a better solution)
<a href='#' class='systemname' data-id="1" data-points="x350y210">system 1</a>
<a href='#' class='systemname' data-id="2" data-points="x120y410">system 2</a>

bearing in mind there can be up to 20 links on the page
I have tried googling but only results seem to be for a single link on a page and not multiple

You can use the jquery data() function to read data attributes on the item.
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".systemname").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var [x, y] = $(this).data("points").substring(1).split("y");

    $("#mapcontent").css("background-image", "url(<?=$imglnk?>)");
    $("#pointer").css({"left": x + "px", "top": y + "px"});
    $("#systeminfo").load('getsysteminfo.php?id='+id);
    
  });
});
</script>


Thankyou Jessegavin I did not know how to access the 'data' properties,, but you made it easy for me to understand, I now have my page working without displaying the coords and ID
